# What is a data structure that represents multiple collections?

Tags: c#, .net

I have an existing application with objects like so.

```
class MyObject{
    public MyCollection  TypeOnes;
    public MyCollection  TypeTwos;
    public MyCollection  TypeThrees;

    public MyCollection  All;
}

class MyCollection : Collection{
    public boolean IsLoaded;
}
```

And it is loaded like this.

```
//using bool array for flag simplicity in example
public void Load(ref MyObject obj, bool[] flags){
    if(flags[0]){
        obj.TypeOnes = LoadOnes();
        obj.TypeOnes.IsLoaded = true;
    }else{
        obj.TypeOnes = new MyCollection();
    }

    if(flags[1]){
        obj.TypeTwos = LoadTwos();
        obj.TypeTwos.IsLoaded = true;
    }else{
        obj.TypeTwos= new MyCollection();
    }

    if(flags[2]){
        obj.TypeThrees = LoadThrees();
        obj.TypeThrees.IsLoaded = true;
    } else {
        obj.TypeThrees = new MyCollection();
    }

    if(flags[3]){
        obj.All = obj.TypeOnes.Clone().AddRange(obj.TypeTwos.Clone()).AddRange(obj.TypeThrees.Clone());
        obj.All.IsLoaded = true;
    } else {
        obj.All = new MyCollection();
    }
}
```

As you can plainly see the `All` collection that is supposed to represent all of the Types will be out of sync unless all types are loaded at once with the `All` collection.

What I'm going to do is make a single flag to load all of the type collections, however, I would like to keep the `All` collection to use to access all of the Type Collections at once and have them in sync in order to limit the amount of refactoring I'm going to have to do. I want it to be read/write so that if I make a change to the `TypeOnes` collection it will be reflected in the `All` collection and vice versa.

Is there an existing DataType that I can use for this?
If not what kind of data structure am I looking to build?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about something like this? `Concat` will merge the collections and return all of them at once.

```
class MyObject
{
    public MyCollection  TypeOnes;
    public MyCollection  TypeTwos;
    public MyCollection  TypeThrees;

    public IEnumerable<T> All
    {
        get { return TypeOnes.Concat(TypeTwos.Concat(TypeThrees));}
        // You can use Union() to handle duplicates as well, but it's slower.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Unless you have a specific reason to create a clone of the objects in the three contained collection, why not implement `All` as an `IEnumerable<T>` (or IEnumerable if you're using pre-generic .NET), something like:

```
// Option: Preserve duplicates between collections
public IEnumerable<T> All()
{
    // Ensure child collections are loaded
    return TypeOnes.Concat(TypeTwos).Concat(TypeThrees);
}

// Option remove duplicates between collections
public IEnumerable<T> All()
{
    // Ensure child collections are loaded
    return TypeOnes.Union(TypeTwos).Union(TypeThrees);
}
```

That way the existing code contract for adding things to the contained collections is maintained, and you are ensured that `All` is never stale or out of sync with those collections.

Note that with the old code contract, `All` became out of sync with the contained collections after it was initialized (since updates to the children were not reflected into `All`).  This is a change in behavior that may or may not be acceptable.

Comment: Unless there is a specific reason to need to remove duplicates, `Concat` reduces overhead in terms of speed and memory footprint over `Union`.

Comment: @Servy: Good point.  I have been working extensively with `HashSet<T>` for the last few days and have visions of them dancing in my head :-)  Updating.

Comment: +1 Good point on using Union instead of  `Concat`: if objects are duplicated in some collection than Union produces correct result.

Comment: wouldn't simple  List<MyCollection> does the job

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov It depends on whether or not you *want* to remove duplicates.  You may not even want to.  You should made the decision to use `Union` over `Concat` if there is a specific reason for which duplicates are both not allowed, and can possibly occur.  When in that case, `Union` is absolutely the right method and is very useful, but those conditions aren't always met.

Comment: @Saurabh: Generating a new list would use more memory, and the list is no longer in sync with the child collections (which may or may not be what is needed).

Comment: @Saurabh Yes, that can work too, depending on what needs to be done.  Note that if you have a collection of collections you could use `SelectMany` to get a flattened sequence of all of the items.  You would need to keep it up to date as you assign new sub-lists though, which would be hard if you didn't change the fields to properties.

Answer (score 2):

Possible approach - expose "all" as `IEnumerable<Base_type_for_items_in_other_collections>` and create it on demand by concatenating other collections. I.e. if you have small list of collections basic [Enumerable.Concat](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb302894.aspx) would work:

```
public IEnumerabe<MyObject> All {get
{
   return TypeOnes.Concat(TypeTwos.Concat(TypeThrees));
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since there might be a lot of items you can consider `yield return` to return items so caller can stop accessing items when appropriate limit were reached/item was found.

```
public class MyObject
{
    public MyCollection  TypeOnes { get; set;} 
    public MyCollection  TypeTwos { get; set;} 
    public MyCollection  TypeThrees { get; set;} 

    public IEnumerable<string> All
    {
        get
        {
            foreach (var item in TypeOnes.Union(TypeTwos).Union(TypeThrees))
            {
                yield return item;
            }
        }
    }
}

public class MyCollection : Collection<string>
{
    public bool IsLoaded { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: There's no reason to iterate your Union.  Just return it.  It is already `IEnumerable<T>`.

Comment: And what about yield return? It does item by item return

Comment: You don't need to do the `yield return` yourself.  If you just do `return TypeOnes.Union(TypeTwos).Union(TypeThrees)`, the "yielding" will be done internally by the .NET framework when `All` is iterated.

Answer (score 0):

All you really need is an ICollection interface or IEnumerable interface that covers all your other collections in a union, right? I assume you won't be adding items to the All collection once you've loaded everything. If that's the case, try:

For the declaration of All:

```
public IEnumerable<MyBaseType>  All;
```

To set All:

```
obj.All = System.Linq.Enumerable.Concat<MyBaseType>(
          obj.TypeOnes, obj.TypeTwos).Concat(obj.TypeThrees);
```

That should allow All to reflect changes in the other collections even if it doesn't allow you to add items directly to it.